# Select rows horizontally in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have Employee SQL Table (SQL Sever 2005):

```
EmployeeID Field1 Field2
121212     MISC1  ABC
121212     MISC2  XYZ
121213     MISC1  AAA
121213     MISC2  BBB
```

I would like to display the result like:

```
EmployeeID MISC1 MISC2
121212     ABC   XYZ
121213     AAA   BBB
```

Please advise and thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Check whether your version supports PIVOT.

Comment: Looks like it is: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx When PIVOT and UNPIVOT are used against databases that are upgraded to SQL Server 2005 or later, the compatibility level of the database must be set to 90 or higher. For information about how to set the database compatibility level, see sp_dbcmptlevel (Transact-SQL).

Comment: I googled this before but didn't help. Any other idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using conditional aggregation

```
SELECT
    EmployeeID,
    MISC1 = MAX(CASE WHEN Field1 = 'MISC1' THEN Field2 END),
    MISC2 = MAX(CASE WHEN Field1 = 'MISC2' THEN Field2 END)
FROM tbl
GROUP BY EmployeeID
```

If you want to do it dynamically:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT @sql = 
'SELECT
    EmployeeID' + CHAR(10) +
(SELECT
'   , MAX(CASE WHEN Field1 = ''' + Field1 +''' THEN Field2 END) AS ' + QUOTENAME(Field1) + CHAR(10)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT Field1 FROM tbl
)t
FOR XML PATH('')
) +
'FROM tbl
GROUP BY EmployeeID;';

EXEC(@sql);
```

Reference: [Cross Tabs and Pivots by Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/)